# Writing hard disk and keyboard driver

Tags: linux, operating-system, driver

I am a complete newbie to operating system and aiming to write my own kernel.
I understand that i will have to write my own device drivers as well.
How do i start with writing my driver?
The tasks of project are as follows.

1.Defining GDT in assembly language

2.Creating boot sector

3.Interrupt handling

4.Screen Driver

5.Keyboard driver

6.Hard disk driver

7.File system

8.I/O programming

9.Physical memory management

Also is it possible to do this in 3 months ( team of 2 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know (or about to find out) OSes are extremely complicated and interconnected. For example, how are you going to have a working Keyboard driver *before* you have implemented interrupt handling?

It sounds like your question actually is: "How do I start writing my own OS?" You start by reading "Required Knowledge," "Beginner Mistakes," and "Getting Started" on [osdev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).

Good luck, and it is going to take a long time... especially if you are learning as you go (which is okay, since your goal is learning and not to make a commercial OS).

**Edit:** Modifying the Linux kernel is a good way to learn about the internals of an OS. It will let you focus on individual aspects (such as just writing a keyboard driver) and your work environment will be sane. Depending on what you want to do, you will be able to further ease development by creating a kernel module instead directly modifying the kernel.

1. Define your project and its scope
2. Set up your work environment (my suggestion, run [Ubuntu Server in QEMU](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/QemuEmulator))
3. Learn how to either boot a custom kernel or use the module system
4. Get to work!

Comment: Thank You.I have taken up operating system as a project based course.Which is about 3 months. Learning is certainly the highest priority but i still have to submit a project.( suggestions are welcome )

Comment: In that case, you may want to look at modifying in some way the Linux kernel. This will get your hands dirty with OSes, but let you focus on a single aspect while retaining your sanity.

Comment: on the same lines look on minix, it has loads of todo and you can learn and also contribute a significant part to the open source. :)

Comment: The book operating systems design and implementation covers the design and code for minix, you can find the PDF online for free and the code is downloadable, It goes through the basics and another book called Unix for super users covers how to write device drivers briefly so that may help as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try looking into contributing to minix (http://www.minix3.org/)

There are a loads of things that are needed to be done .Have a look at (http://wiki.minix3.org/Wishlist).